# array in object in ng-options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I am having problems in getting an array inside of an object into an ng-options.

I have following array of objects with inside another array:

```
$scope.array = [{name: "jan", ar=["car", "bus", "bike"]}, {name: "tom", ar=["milk", "water", "bike", "walking"]}, {name: "kim", ar=["star", "car"]}]
```

I would like to make a select with the options jan, tom and kim. But that isn't a problem:

```
<select ng-options="o.name for o in array" ng-model="choosen.nOption">
```

however when they choose an option a new select should start with as options the array ar from that name:

```
<select ng-if="choosen.nOption!=undefined" ng-options="o.ar for o in array.ar | filter: {name: choosen.nOption}">
```

Can anyone help how I could get the values of the inside array?

You can find a fiddler at https://jsfiddle.net/brokenhip/phxyap8a/

Solution: 
https://jsfiddle.net/brokenhip/phxyap8a/2/

```
<select ng-options="o.name for o in arrayA" ng-model="choosen.nOption"></select>

         <select  ng-if="choosen.nOption!=undefined" ng-options="o for o in choosen.nOption.ar" ng-model="choosen.nOption2"> </select>
```

Comment: my attempt of getting the array ar out of the array as the filter should point to the correct object. I know that isn't right but was the best I could do. Actually I should get ar out of the object inside the array where the name in the object is selected.

Comment: Try `ng-options="o.ar for o in array | filter: {name: choosen.nOption}`

Comment: sadly that doesn't work. I suppose this tries to place the complete array ar in one option or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So i found an easy way is to use $watch to see when the first select change.

In your controller add this :

```
    $scope.$watch('choosen.nOption',function(newVal){
          $scope.choosenOption = newVal['ar'];
          console.log($scope.choosenOption); // check in your console
      });
```

And in your HTML, you don't need a filter:

```
  <select  ng-if="choosen.nOption!=undefined" ng-options="opt for opt in choosenOption" ng-model="choosen.nOption2"> </select>
```

Comment: thanks that works although I always try to only use watches if nothing else is possible.

Comment: I just figured out how to do it without a watch. Don't know why I didn't see it sooner. https://jsfiddle.net/brokenhip/phxyap8a/2/

Comment: Ah your right ! Same for me this is the easiest way. So easy ... :)

Comment: actually I think I tried it once like that but in my app I also need an ng-change else I can't get it to work.